# ggplot2 geom_errorbar not accepting continuous color scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to color some errorbars based on the value of a continuous variable. It produces an error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Here is sample of the data:

```
popdata <- structure(list(state_name = structure(c(3L, 8L, 17L, 10L, 20L, 
7L, 14L, 5L, 15L, 11L, 19L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 18L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 16L, 
13L), .Label = c("38075", "16061", "17123", "01029", "42057", 
"48299", "19067", "37039", "22083", "21005", "47071", "16057", 
"39039", "36017", "29201", "20057", "27035", "48427", "48061", 
"39035"), class = "factor"), low = c(0.059837713753631, 0.12202164206081, 
0.0787897528614793, 0.114032453341537, 0.148341308923047, 0.12706787216107, 
0.12274383236656, 0.0748379645570958, 0.15221930873579, 0.183733602914917, 
0.235290802271188, 0.164149979506739, 0.107250926481166, 0.11777709831118, 
0.223030101604386, 0.0367333722034264, 0.0672672733525947, 0.0783039335836511, 
0.211986216346096, 0.129363157696044), high = c(0.09668764742318, 
0.158453141004957, 0.0952271927220508, 0.145718902550631, 0.153078926872484, 
0.167159039955223, 0.146691963769807, 0.110326114620514, 0.177443038767736, 
0.221222794006902, 0.243313847555343, 0.201423981526801, 0.14822761364434, 
0.143842795549539, 0.242206666862943, 0.0963491004746789, 0.100396455887465, 
0.152986449716942, 0.237907857617593, 0.155683357367624), pop.under6yrs = c(779, 
1365, 4482, 1698, 87596, 1169, 3092, 990, 3295, 1737, 43427, 
1623, 988, 2540, 7431, 228, 1039, 249, 3959, 2680), type = c("Empirical Bayes estimate", 
"Measured rate", "Measured rate", "Measured rate", "Measured rate", 
"Empirical Bayes estimate", "Measured rate", "Empirical Bayes estimate", 
"Measured rate", "Empirical Bayes estimate", "Empirical Bayes estimate", 
"Measured rate", "Measured rate", "Empirical Bayes estimate", 
"Empirical Bayes estimate", "Measured rate", "Measured rate", 
"Empirical Bayes estimate", "Empirical Bayes estimate", "Measured rate"
), rate = c(0.0772670083762154, 0.139880882476302, 0.0865854200764759, 
0.129427522078593, 0.150707738634344, 0.146552623015333, 0.134513369024505, 
0.0918203369486423, 0.164881354080928, 0.202157936735647, 0.239290959114104, 
0.183181736988013, 0.12691131498471, 0.130537078580802, 0.232550431594941, 
0.0558337214718211, 0.0819252242429744, 0.112969248262823, 0.224816181949421, 
0.142364418366184)), .Names = c("state_name", "low", "high", 
"pop.under6yrs", "type", "rate"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the ggplot code:

```
popdata %>% 
ggplot(aes(rate, state_name, color = type)) +
geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = low, xmax = high, color = pop.under6yrs)) +
geom_point(size = 1) +
xlim(0, NA) +
labs(x = "Rate of poverty",
     y = NULL, title = "Measured Rates, Empirical Bayesian Estimates, and Credible Intervals")
```

Additionally, once this becomes functional I would like to use scale_color_gradient() for the errobars, but I"m not sure how to designate the scale color for the errorbars separately from that of the points.

Comment: You have two different variables mapped to color (`type`--discrete and `pop.under6yrs`--continuous). ggplot only allows you to map one set of values to a particular aesthetic.

Comment: You could use a filled point marker in `geom_point` by doing, say, `geom_point(aes(fill=type), size = 2, pch=21)` (and get rid of the `color=type` in the main ggplot call), but then you'll have two different color mappings, which will be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @epi10, you were trying to map `color` to two different variables. `Shape 21` is a hollow circle that accepts the `fill` mapping, meaning that you can then use `fill` for one and `color` for the other. Their colors can then be adjusted manually using `scale_fill_manual` (for discrete) and `scale_colour_gradient` (for continuous).

```
library(ggplot2)

cols<-c("Empirical Bayes estimate"='red','Measured rate'='black')

popdata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rate, state_name,fill=type)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = low, xmax = high, color = pop.under6yrs),size=1) +
  geom_point(size = 3,shape=21) +
  xlim(0, NA) +
  labs(x = "Rate of poverty",
       y = NULL, title = "Measured Rates, Empirical Bayesian Estimates, and Credible Intervals")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=cols)+
  scale_colour_gradient2(low='light blue',mid='blue',high='dark blue',midpoint=45000)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone.  This is a passable solution.  I'm curious though: if I set the aesthetics for color within the geom call rather than the global ggplot call, shouldn't it consider them separately since they are contained for only that geom?  (Or even if I set one globally, the presence of a different aesthetics call within a geom should override it).